# How to handle a singleton?

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm extending some code that wasn't originally written by me and a singleton has been used (although from what I've read it might not quite be properly implemented). Regardless, the singleton itself shouldn't really have to change I don't think. Here's what I've got:

```
class WindowManager
{
    private:
        static WindowManager*           s_wndmgr; //A singleton maintains a pointer to itself as a class variable

        //To ensure the integrity of a singleton
        //Constructors and the destructor should remain private
        WindowManager();
        ~WindowManager();

    public:
        static void Create();
        static void Destroy();
        static inline WindowManager* Get()
        {
            return s_wndmgr;
        }
        void Render();
}
```

---

```
WindowManager* WindowManager::s_wndmgr = NULL;

WindowManager::WindowManager()
{
    s_wndmgr = NULL;
}

WindowManager::~WindowManager()
{
    //Cleanup other stuff if necessary

    delete s_wndmgr;
}

void WindowManager::Create()
{
    if ( !s_wndmgr ) s_wndmgr = new WindowManager();
}

void WindowManager::Destroy()
{
    if ( s_wndmgr ) delete s_wndmgr;
}
```

I've not been exposed to singletons before and I'm fairly new to C++ itself. For me, I'm used to instantiating classes where a constructor would be called, but in this case I can see that the `Create` function handles that, but how does that all tie in to calling `Create` from another class and then using `Get` to return the instance allowing me to call a member function like `Render`?

I know this is far from correct but here's what I'm wanting to do:

```
class myotherclass
{
    private:
        WindowManager*  m_wmgr;         //Window manager
}

 WindowManager::Create();  //This line being the real issue here
 m_wnmgr = WindowManager::Get();
 m_wnmgr->Render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the caller to have to call `Create()`. It could be hidden inside `Get()`. If the singleton instance needs to be created it will. This is called lazy initialization.

```
static inline WindowManager* Get()
{
    Create();
    return s_wndmgr;
}
```

You could remove the `Create()` method completely and move it into `Get()`:

```
static inline WindowManager* Get()
{
    if ( !s_wndmgr ) s_wndmgr = new WindowManager();
    return s_wndmgr;
}
```

Or better yet, get rid of the private pointer and return a reference instead of a pointer:

```
static inline WindowManager& Get()
{
    static WindowManager instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Then, just use it like this:

```
m_wnmgr = WindowManager::Get();
m_wnmgr.Render();
```

There really is no issue with the caller having to call `Create()` as in the code you posted, except in the case where that is forgotten and an uninitialized pointer is returned and used. It's good to protect yourself from even having the chance to forget something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a fairly large scale project and I have several singletons so what has been done here is I have a Singleton class object that is a base class to all singletons. It has a protected constructor so that you can not create a Singleton object directly but any class that derives from it which is a Singleton Type Object can be. Here is the declaration and definition to my Singleton Class.

**Singleton.h**

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

class Singleton {
public:
    enum SingletonType {
        TYPE_LOGGER = 0, // Must Be First!
        TYPE_SETTINGS,
        TYPE_ENGINE,
        TYPE_ANIMATION_MANAGER,
        TYPE_SHADER_MANAGER,
        TYPE_ASSET_STORAGE,
        TYPE_AUDIO_MANAGER,
        TYPE_FONT_MANAGER,
        TYPE_BATCH_MANAGER,     
    }; // Type

private:
    SingletonType m_eType;
public:
    virtual ~Singleton();

protected:
    explicit Singleton( SingletonType eType );

    void    logMemoryAllocation( bool isAllocated ) const;

private:
    Singleton( const Singleton& c ); // Not Implemented
    Singleton& operator=( const Singleton& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // Singleton

#endif // SINGLETON_H
```

**Singleton.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "Singleton.h"
#include "Settings.h"

struct SingletonInfo {
    const std::string strSingletonName;
    bool              isConstructed;

    SingletonInfo( const std::string& strSingletonNameIn ) :
        strSingletonName( strSingletonNameIn ),
        isConstructed( false )
    {}
}; // SingletonInfo

// Order Must Match Types Defined In Singleton::SingletonType enum
static std::array<SingletonInfo, 9> s_aSingletons = { SingletonInfo( "Logger" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "Settings" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "Engine" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "AnimationManager" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "ShaderManager" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "AssetStorage" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "AudioManager" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "FontManager" ),
                                                      SingletonInfo( "BatchManager" ) };

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Singleton()
Singleton::Singleton( SingletonType eType ) :
m_eType( eType ) {

    bool bSaveInLog = s_aSingletons.at( TYPE_LOGGER ).isConstructed;

    try {
        if ( !s_aSingletons.at( eType ).isConstructed ) {
            // Test Initialization Order
            for ( int i = 0; i < eType; ++i ) {
                if ( !s_aSingletons.at( i ).isConstructed ) {
                    throw ExceptionHandler( s_aSingletons.at( i ).strSingletonName + " must be constructed before constructing " + s_aSingletons.at( eType ).strSingletonName, bSaveInLog  );
                }
            }
            s_aSingletons.at( eType ).isConstructed = true;

            if ( s_aSingletons.at( TYPE_ENGINE ).isConstructed &&
                Settings::get()->isDebugLoggingEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
                logMemoryAllocation( true );
            }

        } else {
            throw ExceptionHandler( s_aSingletons.at( eType ).strSingletonName + " can only be constructed once.", bSaveInLog );
        }
    } catch ( std::exception& ) {
        // eType Is Out Of Range
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Invalid Singleton Type Specified: " << eType;
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream, bSaveInLog );
    }
} // Singleton    

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ~Singleton()
Singleton::~Singleton() {
    if ( s_aSingletons.at( TYPE_ENGINE ).isConstructed &&
        Settings::get()->isDebugLoggingEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
        logMemoryAllocation( false );
    }

    s_aSingletons.at( m_eType ).isConstructed = false;
} // ~Singleton

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// logMemoryAllocation()
void Singleton::logMemoryAllocation( bool isAllocated ) const {
    if ( isAllocated ) {
        Logger::log( "Created " + s_aSingletons.at( m_eType ).strSingletonName );
    } else {
        Logger::log( "Destroyed " + s_aSingletons.at( m_eType ).strSingletonName );
    }
} // logMemoryAllocation
```

I will show what 2 of the derived classes look like; the Logger & Settings Classes

**Logger.h**

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include "Singleton.h"

class Logger sealed : public Singleton {
public:
    // Number Of Items In Enum Type Must Match The Number Of Items
    // And Order Of Items Stored In s_aLogTypes
    enum LoggerType {
        TYPE_INFO = 0,
        TYPE_WARNING,
        TYPE_ERROR,
        TYPE_CONSOLE,
    }; // Type

private:
    std::string m_strLogFilename;
    unsigned    m_uMaxCharacterLength;

    std::array<std::string, 4>  m_aLogTypes;
    const std::string           m_strUnknownLogType;

    HANDLE m_hConsoleOutput;
    WORD   m_consoleDefaultColor;

public:
    explicit Logger( const std::string& strLogFilename );
    virtual ~Logger();

    static void log( const std::string& strText, LoggerType eLogType = TYPE_INFO );
    static void log( const std::ostringstream& strStreamText, LoggerType eLogType = TYPE_INFO );
    static void log( const char* szText,  LoggerType eLogType = TYPE_INFO );

private:
    Logger( const Logger& c ); // Not Implemented
    Logger& operator=( const Logger&  c ); // Not Implemented

}; // Logger

#endif // LOGGER_H
```

**Logger.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "BlockThread.h"
#include "TextFileWriter.h"

static Logger* s_pLogger = nullptr;
static CRITICAL_SECTION s_criticalSection;

static const WORD WHITE_ON_RED = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED; // White Text On Red Background

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Logger()
// Initialize A File To Be Used For Logging
Logger::Logger( const std::string& strLogFilename ) :
Singleton( TYPE_LOGGER ),
m_strLogFilename( strLogFilename ),
m_uMaxCharacterLength( 0 ),
m_strUnknownLogType( "UNKNOWN" ) {

    // Oder Must Match Types Defined In Logger::Type enum
    m_aLogTypes[0] = "Info";
    m_aLogTypes[1] = "Warning";
    m_aLogTypes[2] = "Error";
    m_aLogTypes[3] = ""; // Console

    // Find Widest Log Type String
    m_uMaxCharacterLength = m_strUnknownLogType.size();
    for each( const std::string& strLogType in m_aLogTypes ) {
        if ( m_uMaxCharacterLength < strLogType.size() ) {
             m_uMaxCharacterLength = strLogType.size();
        }
    }

    InitializeCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );
    BlockThread blockTread( s_criticalSection ); // Enter Critical Section

    // Start Log File
    TextFileWriter file( m_strLogFilename, false, false );

    // Prepare Console
    m_hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleInfo;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( m_hConsoleOutput, &consoleInfo );
    m_consoleDefaultColor = consoleInfo.wAttributes;

    s_pLogger = this;

    logMemoryAllocation( true );

} // Logger

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ~Logger()
Logger::~Logger() {
    logMemoryAllocation( false );

    s_pLogger = nullptr;

    DeleteCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );
} // ~Logger

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// log( const std::string )
void Logger::log( const std::string& strText, LoggerType eLogType ) {
    log( strText.c_str(), eLogType );
} // log( const std::string )

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// log( const std::ostringstream )
void Logger::log( const std::ostringstream& strStreamText, LoggerType eLogType ) {
    log( strStreamText.str().c_str(), eLogType );
} // log( const std::ostringstream )

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// log( const char* )
void Logger::log( const char* szText, LoggerType eLogType ) {

    if ( nullptr == s_pLogger ) {
        std::cout << "Logger has not been initialized, can not log " << szText << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection ); // Enter Critical Section

    std::ostringstream strStream;

    // Default White Text On Red Background
    WORD textColor = WHITE_ON_RED;

    // Chose Log Type Text String, Display "UNKNOWN" If eLogType Is Out Of Range
    strStream << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw( s_pLogger->m_uMaxCharacterLength );

    try {
        if ( TYPE_CONSOLE != eLogType ) {
            strStream << s_pLogger->m_aLogTypes.at( eLogType );
        }
        if ( TYPE_WARNING == eLogType ) {
            // Yellow
            textColor = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN;
        } else if ( TYPE_INFO == eLogType ) {
            // Green
            textColor = FOREGROUND_GREEN;
        } else if ( TYPE_CONSOLE == eLogType ) {
            // Cyan
            textColor = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE;
        }
    } catch( ... ) {
        strStream << s_pLogger->m_strUnknownLogType;
    }

    // Date And Time
    if ( TYPE_CONSOLE != eLogType ) {
        SYSTEMTIME time;
        GetLocalTime( &time );

        strStream << " [" << time.wYear << "."
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wMonth << "."
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wDay << " "
            << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wHour << ":"
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wMinute << ":"
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wSecond << "."
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw( 3 ) << time.wMilliseconds << "] ";
    }
    strStream << szText << std::endl;

    // Log Message
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( s_pLogger->m_hConsoleOutput, textColor );
    std::cout << strStream.str();

    // Save Message To Log File
    try {
        TextFileWriter file( s_pLogger->m_strLogFilename, true, false );
        file.write( strStream.str() );

    } catch( ... ) {
        // Not Saved In Log File, Write Message To Console
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " failed to write to file: " << strStream.str() << std::endl;
    }

    // Reset To Default Color
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( s_pLogger->m_hConsoleOutput, s_pLogger->m_consoleDefaultColor );

} // log( const char* )
```

**Settings.h**

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H
#define SETTINGS_H

#include "Singleton.h"

class Settings sealed : public Singleton {
public:
    enum DebugLogging {
        DEBUG_NONE      = 0,
        DEBUG_MEMORY    = ( 1 << 0 ),
        DEBUG_RENDER    = ( 1 << 1 ),
        DEBUG_GUI       = ( 1 << 2 ),

        DEBUG_ALL       = 0xffffffff
    }; // DebugLogging

private:
    unsigned        m_uPhysicsRefreshRateHz;
    bool            m_isWindowedMode;
    unsigned long   m_uRandNumGenSeed;
    glm::uvec2      m_gamePixelSize;
    glm::uvec2      m_openglVersion;
    DebugLogging    m_eDebugLogging;

public:
    static Settings* const get();

    Settings();
    virtual ~Settings();

    std::string getNameAndVersion() const;

    void    setRandomNumberSeed( unsigned long uSeedValue );

    void    setWindowDisplayMode( bool isWindowed );
    bool    isWindowDisplayMode() const;

    void            setDebugLogging( DebugLogging eDebugLogging );
    void            setDebugLogging( unsigned uDebugLogging );
    DebugLogging    getDebugLogging() const;
    bool            isDebugLoggingEnabled( DebugLogging eDebugLogging ) const;

    void                setGameSize( const glm::uvec2& uGamePixelSize );
    const glm::uvec2&   getGameSize() const;

    double  getPhysicsStepSeconds() const;

    std::string showSummary() const;

    void                setOpenglVersion( const glm::uvec2& version );
    const glm::uvec2&   getOpenglVersion() const;

private:
    Settings( const Settings& c ); // Not Implemented
    Settings& operator=( const Settings& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // Settings

#endif // SETTINGS_H
```

**Settings.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Settings.h"
#include "BuildConfig.h"

static Settings* s_pSettings = nullptr;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// get()
Settings* const Settings::get() {
    if ( nullptr == s_pSettings ) {
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " failed, Settings has not been constructed yet" ) );
    }
    return s_pSettings;
} // get

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Settings()
Settings::Settings() :
Singleton( TYPE_SETTINGS ),
m_uPhysicsRefreshRateHz( 100 ), // Should Not Be Less Then 24Hz
m_isWindowedMode( false ),
m_uRandNumGenSeed( 0 ),
m_gamePixelSize( 1024, 768 ),
m_openglVersion( 0, 0 ),
m_eDebugLogging( DEBUG_NONE ) {
    s_pSettings = this;

    logMemoryAllocation( true );
} // Settings

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ~Settings()
Settings::~Settings() {
    logMemoryAllocation( false );
    s_pSettings = nullptr;
} // ~Settings

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getNameAndVersion()
std::string Settings::getNameAndVersion() const {
    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << g_strGameName
        << " v" << g_iMajorVersion << "." << g_iMinorVersion << "." << g_iBuildNumber;
    return strStream.str();
} // getNameAndVersion

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setRandomNumberSeed()
void Settings::setRandomNumberSeed( unsigned long uSeedValue ) {
    m_uRandNumGenSeed = uSeedValue;
} // setRandomNumberSeed

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setWindowDisplayMode()
void Settings::setWindowDisplayMode( bool isWindowed ) {
    m_isWindowedMode = isWindowed;
} // setWindowDisplayMode

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// isWindowDisplayMode()
bool Settings::isWindowDisplayMode() const {
    return m_isWindowedMode;
} // isWindowDisplayMode

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setDebugLogging()
void Settings::setDebugLogging( DebugLogging eDebugLogging ) {
    m_eDebugLogging = eDebugLogging;
} // setDebugLogging

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setDebugLogging()
void Settings::setDebugLogging( unsigned uDebugLogging ) {
    m_eDebugLogging = static_cast<Settings::DebugLogging>( uDebugLogging );
} // setDebugLogging

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getDebugLogging()
Settings::DebugLogging Settings::getDebugLogging() const {
    return m_eDebugLogging;
} // getDebugLogging

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// isDebugLoggingEnabled()
bool Settings::isDebugLoggingEnabled( DebugLogging eDebugLogging ) const {
    return ( (m_eDebugLogging & eDebugLogging ) > 0 );
} // isDebugLoggingEnabled

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setGameSize()
void Settings::setGameSize( const glm::uvec2& uGamePixelSize ) {
    m_gamePixelSize = glm::uvec2( glm::clamp( uGamePixelSize.x, 800U, 2048U ),
                                  glm::clamp( uGamePixelSize.y, 600U, 2048U ) );
} // setGameSize

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getGameSize
const glm::uvec2& Settings::getGameSize() const {
    return m_gamePixelSize;
} // getGameSize

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getPhysicsStepSeconds()
double Settings::getPhysicsStepSeconds() const {
    return ( 1.0 / static_cast<double>( m_uPhysicsRefreshRateHz ) );
} // getPhysicsStepSeconds

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// showSummary()
std::string Settings::showSummary() const {
    int iWidth = 53;
    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << "Game Settings: " << std::endl;

    // OpenGL Version
    strStream << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw( iWidth ) << "OpenGL: " << m_openglVersion.x << "." << m_openglVersion.y << std::endl;

    // Random Number Generator Seed Value
    strStream << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw( iWidth ) << "Seed Value: " << m_uRandNumGenSeed << std::endl;

    // Render Mode And Size
    strStream << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw( iWidth ) << "Render Mode: " << ( m_isWindowedMode ? "Window" : "Full Screen" ) << std::endl;
    strStream << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw( iWidth ) << "Game Screen Resolution: " << m_gamePixelSize.x << "x" << m_gamePixelSize.y << " pixels" << std::endl;

    // Refresh Settings
    strStream << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw( iWidth ) << "Physics Refresh: " << m_uPhysicsRefreshRateHz << " Hz" << std::endl;

    return strStream.str();
} // showSummary

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setOpenglVersion()
void Settings::setOpenglVersion( const glm::uvec2& version ) {
    if ( version.x < 2 ) {
        // Using Older OpenGL 1.x
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " " << g_strGameName << " requires OpenGL v2+ to be supported";
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    m_openglVersion = version;
} // setOpenglVersion

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getOpenglVersion()
const glm::uvec2& Settings::getOpenglVersion() const {
    return m_openglVersion;
} // getOpenglVersion
```

Obviously this will not build nor compile on your machine because some of these classes depend on other classes not shown here. However the Singleton Base class does not depend on anything not shown. There are multiple ways to implement a working singleton object. Credit for these class objects goes to Marek A. Krzeminski which can be found at [www.MarekKnows.com](http://www.MarekKnows.com)

Answer (score 0):

you really don't need a separate "Get" method. The call to static method "Create" shall return a pointer to WindowManager instance (will be created if one does not exist)

```
class WindowManager
{
    private:
        static WindowManager*           s_wndmgr; //A singleton maintains a pointer to itself as a class variable

        //To ensure the integrity of a singleton
        //Constructors and the destructor should remain private
        WindowManager();
        ~WindowManager();

    public:
        static WindowManager* Create();
        static void Destroy();
        void Render();
}

WindowManager* WindowManager::s_wndmgr = NULL;

WindowManager::WindowManager()
{
}

WindowManager::~WindowManager()
{
}

WindowManager* WindowManager::Create()
{
    if ( !s_wndmgr ) 
    {
        s_wndmgr = new(std::nothrow) WindowManager();
    }

    return s_wndmgr;
}

void WindowManager::Destroy()
{
    if ( s_wndmgr )
    {
     delete s_wndmgr;
     s_wndmgr = NULL;
    }
}
```